# Second C Linkage of overloaded function not allowed C2733

Tags: visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors

So I am using Visual Studio 2015 and some online library I found,and in the sample project everything is working, but when i make my own, I get errors.

Errors are found in file cmath.

When i build my project i get 
'abs' , 'pow' , 'abs' , 'acos' , ..., second C linkage of overloaded function not allowed. 
How can i fix this ? I tried setting

Properties->General->Project Defaults -> Character set to Use Multi-Byte Character Set or No set, but still get errors.

Thanks !

**Note 1:**
It looks like inside file cmath there are two functions of each mathematical function that make problem like:

```
_Check_return_ inline double abs(_In_ double _Xx) _NOEXCEPT
{
    return (_CSTD fabs(_Xx));
}

_Check_return_ inline float abs(_In_ float _Xx) _NOEXCEPT
{
    return (_CSTD fabsf(_Xx));
}
```

Why are there two of these functions and why would this represent a problem ?

Comment: You can only #include cmath in a .cpp source file.  Not in a .c source file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File was .cpp and library was for C. So this made some errors, after changing extension of file to .c errors dissapeared